# LinkExtractor RegEx for Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

In Scrapy, I'm using a LinkExtractor to crawl Indeed.com.

```
import scrapy
from indeed.items import IndeedItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class IndeedSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'indeedSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['indeed.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.indeed.com/q-Finance-jobs.html']
    base_url = 'https://www.indeed.com'
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'.+/rc/clk/.+')),
            callback='parse_job', follow=True)]
    def parse_job(self, response):               
            print(response.url)
```

The start_url has plenty of links that follow the pattern `https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk/...`, such as:
https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=e60b87b9a928dfb6&fccid=8067e3333ec64c76&vjs=3

For some reason, none of them are firing. No errors, but parse_job is never being called.

Comment: Can you try `r'.+\/rc\/clk\/.+'` The slashes must be escaped

Comment: No, `/` should not be escaped. They are not any special in string regex patterns.

Comment: Try a compiled regex, `allow=(re.compile(r'/rc/clk/'))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Same result - navigates to the start_url but doesn't crawl any other pages

Comment: I think I've figured out the issue. The links at .../rc/clk.. open up a frame that shows the job info (which I'm trying to scrape), but the URL remains the same. Not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your rule to the following worked just fine for me:

```py
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('rc/clk',)), callback='parse_job'),
    )
```

Because of some redirecting the printed response-urls will be in the form of for example:
https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=e5c790a8fd2310d9&from=serp&vjs=3